# DotnetNuke Module Integration

Tags: c#, integration, module, dotnetnuke

I have created a DNN module for a Poll. This module is created as a  Project within my DNN project solution  . I would like to integrate this module into the DNN website.Is there any chance of doing this? I already change the users controls to inherit PortalModuleBase withing my Poll project.
I went through this tutorial http://www.adefwebserver.com/DotNetNukeHELP/DNN4_SurveyModule/Default.htm  but i realise it s not the same case since this one shows you how to create the module in the DNN site.
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start with the DNN Module wizard for visual studio that comes with the DNN source package.  This will give you a 'hello world' module to start with.

You also need to create a manifest file for your module.  Take a look at [DNN Module Packager](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/DnnModulePackager.aspx).

This XML file will contain the relative paths of all your module files when installed.  The manifest file is zipped along with all your module files and installed in the DNN Host menu when logged in as the host user.

Most of this information and starter modules can be found on the [DNN](http://dotnetnuke.org) website under documentation.

Comment: What if i create a module on a side? In my case i have created a separate project (Poll or Hello World) and want to use it as a Module in DNN.Any chance?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.  The question is where the files are when you test.  The first time around you may need to install using the DNN host user.  But if your project places it's file in the module folder under 'DesktopModules' you should be able to refresh DNN and see your changes.

Comment: But do i still have to create the manifest like u suggested above?or  simply zip my file and get if when the site is live(meaning getting the zip file from host account)?

Comment: You have to create the manifest file and install the package at least once I believe.