# DotNetNuke Visual Studio Projects

Tags: visual-studio, dotnetnuke, project-template, visual-studio-templates

I downloaded the DotNetNuke Visual Studio Installer, and the only project template I got was a Compiled Module. I've seen screen shots and examples where people had 'DNN Project' projects, and 'DNN Skin' projects. Did something go wrong with my installation? Where can I get a template for a DotNetNuke 5 Skin project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to download the package that includes all the DNN source code, not just the basic platform. See [DotnetNuke Module Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144686/dotnetnuke-module-integration)